# Strange splitting issue with finite difference simulation of telegraph-type equation: $W_{tt} + V W_{tx} + k_E V W_x + k W_t = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to simulate the hyperbolic partial differential equation in the title, but I am having trouble finding a discrete analog of this equation which is numerically stable. The equation is:
$$W_{tt} + V W_{tx} + k_E V W_x + k W_t = 0$$
My first attempt was to introduce *central differences* in both space and time. Time and space are discretized via
$t_n = n \Delta t$ and $x_i = i \Delta x$ for $j=1,\dots, N_{iter}$ and $i = 1,\dots,N$. The discrete version of $W$ is written
$$W(x_i,t_n) = W_i^n.$$
Defining the numerical derivatives as
$$\partial_t W_i^n = \frac{W_i^{n+1}-W_i^{n-1}}{2\Delta t},$$
$$\partial_t^2 W_i^n = \frac{W_i^{n+1}-2 W_i^{n-1}+W_i^{n-1}}{\Delta t^2}$$
and similarly for the space component gives the difference equations
$$ -a W_{i-1}^n + (1+c)W_i^{n+1} + a W_{i+1}^{n+1} = b W_{i-1}^n + 2 W_i^n -b W_{i+1}^n \\ - a W_{i-1}^{n-1} + (c-1) W_i^{n-1} + a W_{i+1}^n.$$
Here the parameters $a,b,c$ involve the coefficients in the differential equation, the timestep $\Delta t$, and the grid spacing $\Delta x$.

Assuming the absorbing boundary condition $W_1^n = W_N^n = 0$, these can be written in a matrix form as
$$ A W^{n+1}= B W^n + C W^{n-1},$$
where each of the matrices $A,B,C$ are tri-diagonal and involve constant coefficients composed of $a,b,c$.

I formulated the matrices, and set up the following type of loop to simulate the PDE:

```
W0=W1=P # The first two iterations are both to the same initial condition
Ainv = ... # the inverse of A is calculated
for j in range(Niter): # time loop
    W = Ainv@(B@W1+C@W0) # solution of the matrix equation for W
    W0 = W1 # redefine old W
    W1 = W # redefine new W
```

The result seems in a sense half correct. Every second point does what I expect... while the remaining points seem to diverge until they overflow. Here is an image of what I mean. This image demonstrates 5 seconds of evolution from an initially triangular profile. On the right one can see the splitting between two different evolutions, one which works, and another which doesn't.
[image]

Am I missing anything here regarding finite difference simulation of hyperbolic equations? Is there a reason central differences would not work here? I suppose the issue is really that the right-most boundary is not properly behaving as an absorbing boundary.